# Java Card APDU Error

Tags: javacard, apdu

I am trying to send a simple APDU to a Java Card( I attached the simple code of the applet below).I already tested the applet in the Eclipse simulator but when I want to send an APDU to the applet it fails with the following error : `send_APDU() returns 0x80206E00 (6E00: Wrong CLA byte.)` .Applet is already installed into the card ( I used GpShell to do that ) .Here is the full output from the script I used to send the APDU.

```
D:\GPShell-1.4.4>GPShell.exe send_APDU.txt
establish_context
enable_trace
enable_timer
card_connect
command time: 15 ms
send_apdu -sc 0 -APDU b0000000010000
Command --> B0000000010000
Wrapped command --> B0000000010000
Response <-- 6E00
send_APDU() returns 0x80206E00 (6E00: Wrong CLA byte.)
command time: 860 ms
card_disconnect
command time: 31 ms
release_context
command time: 0 ms
```

Here is the full code of the applet.

```
public class Contor extends Applet {

private byte contor = 0;
private final static byte CLS=(byte)0xB0;
private final static byte INC=(byte)0x00;
private final static byte DEC=(byte)0x01;
private final static byte GET=(byte)0x02;
private final static byte INIT=(byte)0x03;

private Contor() {
}

public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
    new Contor().register();
}

public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
    if(this.selectingApplet())return;
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    if(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLS)
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    switch(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
    {
        case INC:contor++;  break;
        case DEC:contor--;  break;
        case GET:
            buffer[0] = contor;
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0,(short)1);
            break;
        case INIT:
            apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
            contor = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA];
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a communication with your applet, you must select your applet first.

To do that you have two options. The first option is making your applet *Default Selected* in the applet installation phase and make it implicitly selected applet after each power up. The second option is sending `SELECT` APDU command concatenated with your applet AUD before sending other commands.

SELECT APDU Command = `00A40400 <AID Length> <AID>`

Other wise, the entity that respond to your command, is not your applet and most probably it is the default Default-Selected applet, i.e. Card Manager.

Comment: Regarding your second point: Since both `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA]` and `CLS` are declared as byte, they both contain the same signed value (i.e. -80 for `(byte)0xB0`) and the comparison will perfectly work. Casting to short/int, truncating and casting back to byte won't change anything and is completely useless in this case.

Comment: @MichaelRoland You are completely right. Thank you. Answer updated. The casting and bit-wise and is required in cases that we comparing buffer elements with a short/int value greater than "127". right?